# What is the right way to update InfoWindow content using PouchDB

Tags: javascript, google-maps, indexeddb, pouchdb

The problem I'm facing is updating InfoWindow content (when marker is clicked). It is too slow. It's not because I've implemented PouchDB in a wrong way. **It's because**:

1. We have more than 500 markers on a map
2. Each marker's data is stored as a doc in PouchDB
3. All docs are updated every 1-15 seconds (That means we're receiving live updates for each marker)

This means whenever we try to get something from DB when update is going on, it takes some time until the ongoing update is completed. It takes 10-20 seconds currently to fetch data (when we click the marker to fetch latest data and update content of InfoWindow).

So is there any way to fix this or is there any better option to do it?

Comment: I'm curious, when fetching only **one** doc, are you waiting for **all** docs to be updated?

Comment: No, I'm not waiting. Think 10 doc updates are currently under progress. I need to fetch data of one of them at the same time. Result is delayed in this case.

Comment: Are you using automatic sync of PouchDB? Which PouchDB sync options are being used?

Comment: What is PouchDB sync? I don't think I'm using anything like this. I'm using IndexedDB in Chrome (idb adapter). The data is stored in browser storage only.

Comment: And If I pause all updates by disconnecting to Internet, I can fetch information without any delay! So it must be something like we can't fetch when any update is going on.

Comment: By PouchDB sync I meant this feature: [PouchDB live replication](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html#live%E2%80%93replication "Live replication")

Comment: No. I don't use `localDB.sync` I just use normal db storage and I've attached "onChange" listener on DB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168906/discussion-between-rahul-and-user3405291).